# Python pickles not storing data

Tags: python, pickle, saving-data, storing-data

I am trying to create a registrar system through Python with pickles.  I have gotten the system to record user input, but it does not save it for future implementations of the program.

Here is the code that will start the program:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pickle as pck
import pathlib
from pathlib import *
from registrar import *

prompt = "Please select an option: \n 1  Create a new course \n 2  Schedule a new course offering \n 3  List this school's course catalogue \n 4  List this school's course schedule \n 5  Hire an instructor \n 6  Assign an instructor to a course \n 7  Enroll a student \n 8  Register a student for a course \n 9  List this school's enrolled students \n 10  List the students that are registered for a course \n 11  Submit a student's grade \n 12  Get student records \n 13 Exit"

farewell = "Thank you for using the Universal University Registrar System.  Goodbye!"

print ("Welcome to the Universal University Registration System.")

print ("\n")

try: #As long as CTRL-C has not been pressed, or 13 not been input by user.

  input_invalid = True
  while input_invalid:
    inst = input("Please enter the name of your institution. ").strip()
    domain = input("Please enter the domain. ").strip().lower()
    if inst == "" or domain == "":
      print("Your entry is invalid.  Try again.")
    else:
      input_invalid = False

  schoolie = Institution(inst, domain)

  if Path(inst + '.pkl').exists() == False:
    with open(inst + '.pkl', 'r+b') as iptschool:
      schoolie = pck.load(iptschool)

  while True:
    print (prompt)
    user_input = input("Please enter your choice:  ") 
    try:
      user_input = int(user_input)
      if user_input < 1 or user_input > 14: #UserInput 14: on prompt.
        raise ValueError("Please enter a number between 1 and 13, as indicated in the menu.")
    except ValueError:
      print("Not a valid number.  Please try again.")

    if user_input == 1: #Create a new course
      input_invalid2 = True #Ensure that the user actually provides the input.
      while input_invalid2:
        input_name = input("Please enter a course name:  ").strip()
        input_department = input("Please enter the course's department:  ").strip()
        input_number = input("Please enter the course's number (just the number, not the departmental prefix):  ").strip()
        try:
          input_number = int(input_number)
        except ValueError:
          print ("Please print an integer. Try again.")
        input_credits = input("Please enter the number of credits awarded for passing this course. Please use an integer:  ").strip()
        try:
          input_credits = int(input_credits)
        except ValueError:
          print ("Please print an integer. Try again.")

        if input_name != "" and input_department != "" and input_number and input_credits:
          input_invalid2 = False #Valid input
        else:
          print("One or more of your entries is invalid.  Try again.")

      added_course = Course(input_name, input_department, input_number, input_credits)
      for course in schoolie.course_catalog:
        if course.department == input_department and course.number == input_number and course.name == input_name:
          print("That course is already in the system.  Try again.")
          input_invalid2 == True
      if input_invalid2 == False:
        schoolie.add_course(added_course)
        print ("You have added course %s %s: %s, worth %d credits."%(input_department,input_number,input_name, input_credits))
```

And here is the second option, which SHOULD reveal that it is stored, but it does not.

```
elif user_input == 2: #Schedule a course offering
      input_invalid2 = True #Ensure that the user actually provides the input.
      while input_invalid2:
        input_department = input("Please input the course's department: ").strip()
        input_number = input("Please input the course's number: ").strip()
        course = None
        courseFound = False
        for c in schoolie.course_catalog:
          if c.department == input_department and c.number == input_number: #Course found in records
            courseFound = True
            course = c
            input_section_number = input("Please enter a section number for this course offering:  ").strip()
            input_instructor = input("If you would like, please enter an instructor for this course offering:  ").strip()
            input_year = input("Please enter a year for this course offering:  ").strip()
            input_quarter = input("Please enter the quarter in which this course offering will be held - either SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, or WINTER:  ").strip().upper()
            if input_course != "" and input_course in schoolie.course_catalog and input_section_number.isdigit() and input_year.isdigit() and input_quarter in ['SPRING', 'SUMMER', 'FALL', 'WINTER'] and input_credits.isdigit():
              if input_instructor != "": #Instructor to be added later, if user chooses option 6.
                added_course_offering = CourseOffering(c, input_section_number, None, input_year, input_quarter)
              else:
                added_course_offering = CourseOffering(c, input_section_number, input_instructor, input_year, input_quarter)
              schoolie.add_course_offering(added_course_offering)
              input_invalid2 = False #Valid input
              print ("You have added course %s, Section %d: %s, worth %d credits."%(input_course,input_section_number,input_name, input_credits))
            else:
              print("One or more of your entries is invalid.  Try again.")
        if courseFound == False: #If course has not been found at the end of the loop:
          print("The course is not in our system.  Please create it before you add an offering.")
          break
```

By the way, I think I have the system closing properly.  Correct me if I'm wrong:

```
   elif user_input == 13: #Exit
      with open(inst + '.pkl', 'wb') as output:
        pck.dump(schoolie, output, pck.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
      del schoolie
      print (farewell)
      sys.exit()

except KeyboardInterrupt: #user pushes Ctrl-C to end the program
  print(farewell)
```

I believe that there is something wrong with the way that I am setting up the pickles files.  I'm creating them, but I seem not to be putting data into them.

I apologize for the long-winded nature of this question, but I hope that the details will help you understand the problems that I've been having.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Saving data in pickle files is probably not the right approach. You might want to use a CSV file or SQLite instead.

Comment: Most of that code is irrelevant to your `pickle` problem (and it's hard to read it with all the long lines). It would be better if your code were a [mcve] that just focuses on the pickling issue. However, I have noticed some odd things. Eg, you test if the .pkl file doesn't exist with `if Path(inst + '.pkl').exists() == False:` but then you try to read it anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the observation.  I was trying to write that if the file doesn't exist, the program should create it.  There's a line missing.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you may have dump and load reversed:  (from the docs)

```
Signature: pck.load(file, *, fix_imports=True, encoding='ASCII', errors='strict')
Docstring:
Read and return an object from the pickle data stored in a file.

Signature: pck.dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)
Docstring:
Write a pickled representation of obj to the open file object file.
```

Answer (score 0):

With all those lines of code, it does get a little confusing, but I don't see any code that is pickling and writing the objects to a file.

Before anything else, you should assign the file to a variable so you can reference it. To do this, you'll have code similar to this:`MyFile = open("FileName.extension","wb")`. `MyFile` can be any name you want, it will be what you use later to reference the file. `FileName` is the name of the file itself. This is the name it will have in File Explorer. `.extension` is the file's extension, specifying the type of file. **You should use `.dat` for this.** `wb` is the file access mode. "w" means write, and "b" means binary. (Pickled objects can only be stored in a binary file.)

To write the pickled objects, you'll need this code:`pck.dump(object,MyFile)`. (Usually, you would use `pickle.dump(object,MyFile)`, but you imported `pickle as pck`.)

After writing the data to the file, you'll want to retrieve it. To do this, the "wb" instance of `MyFile` needs to be closed like this:`MyFile.close()`. Then you'll need to re-open the file in read mode using the following code:`MyFile = open("FileName.extension","rb")` Then you would use this:`object = pickle.load(MyFile)` to read the data. In the preceding example, (the `load` function), your `object` *must* have the same name as when you pickled it using the `dump` function. (`pck.dump(object,MyFile)`)

In the end, you'll end up with something similar to this:

```
if writing conditions are true:
    MyFile = open("FileName.dat","wb")
    pickle.dump(object,MyFile)    # This will be repeated for each object.
    MyFile.close()

if reading conditions are true:
    MyFile = open("FileName.dat","rb")
    object = pickle.load(MyFile)    # This will be repeated for each object.
    MyFile.close()
```

I'm sorry if this wasn't the answer you wanted. Because of all those lines of code, it is somewhat hard to understand. I need clarification to give a better answer.